# Hide Cells based on number selected from Drop Down

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I have two sets of data within my sheet - the first is 1 row per machine, the second is 13 rows per machine. From a drop down box the user will select values from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 which correspond to the number of machines.

When a value is selected the corresponding rows within the two data sets need to be hidden. For example, if the user selects 5, only the rows for machine 1 to 5 will show.

I have the following code so far, but wondering if there is a simplified way of doing this as I haven't yet added in the individual values (1-5), also how do I have this run when the value is select from the drop down list?

```
Sub HideRows()

If Range("F19") = "10" Then
    Rows("31:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("84:473").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("41:60").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("214:473").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("F19") = "15" Then
    Rows("31:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("84:473").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("46:60").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("279:473").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("f19") = "20" Then
    Rows("31:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("84:473").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("51:60").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("344:473").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("f19") = "25" Then
    Rows("31:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("84:473").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("56:60").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("409:473").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("f19") = "30" Then
    Rows("31:60").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("84:473").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm providing a more generic solution. You need to use WOrksheet_Change in the Sheet's Module

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Debug.Print Target.Address

If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then 'change the address to the dropdown box cell you have
    Debug.Print Target.Value
    NumMachineShow = CLng(Target.Value)
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False ' reset, unhidden every row first
    Rows(31 + NumMachineShow & ":60").EntireRow.Hidden = True ' hide the unwanted 1 row per machine here
    Rows(61 + NumMachineShow * 13 & ":473").EntireRow.Hidden = True ' hide the detail, you need to modify the numbers yourself
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code. I copied the code into the module1 of the workbook, and updated cell references and rows, however when I change the value in the drop down box it isn't doing anything? Any ideas..

Comment: you need to copy the code to the Sheet Module, not your own module,
Sheet Moudule means "Sheet1 (Sheet1)" <=== the sheet your dropdown list is in

Comment: Thank you - It seems that when I hit 30 it is hiding the 30th row? Also the only other thing is at the bottom of each range I have a totals column. In the first range which is from rows 31:60 with the totals on rows 61 and 62 when I select a number from the drop down it is currently hiding the totals also - how can I leave them unhidden?

Comment: I don't quite understand your situation, but I believe you can just manipulate the numbers, or split the to Hide Range into 2,3,4 more parts to reach your result.